# Is removing the excess empty pages in a `book` document advisable?

Tags: books

The `book` document class inserts blank pages after the title, table of contents, and the end of each chapter, likely for two-sided pages. However, I do not use two-page view, and I do not intend to print this document or otherwise publish it, so is it a good idea to remove such pages—and if it is, how would I do it?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{The Two Trees}
\author{Rahul Choubey}
\date{August 18, 2020}
\newcommand{\preface}{\chapter*{Preface}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Preface}}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \preface
    \chapter{*insert name here*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass[oneside]{book}`

Comment: "Good idea" is too subjective for this site, but a two page view is definitely more appropriate if you're going to be printing your document.

Comment: Isn't it pretty much a `report` after you do that?